# PHP form not displaying feedback

Tags: php

I'm making a process form in PHP and I'm trying to display the feedback but it's not wanting to show. The code that I have is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .error{color: #FF0000;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Customer Feedback</h1>
        <p1>Please tell us what you think</p1><br><br>

        <?PHP
            $name = trim($_POST[fullname]);
            $email = trim($_POST[email]);
            $text = trim($_POST[feedback]);
        ?>

        <form method='POST' action='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>' >
            <p1>Your name:</p1><br>
            <input type="text" name="fullname" value="<?php echo $fullname; ?>" required><br><br>
            <p1>Your email address:</p1><br>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" required><br><br>
            <p1>Your feedback:</p1><br>
            <textarea rows="5"  cols="50" name="feedback"><?php echo nl2br($text);?></textarea>
            <textarea><?php echo $text;?></textarea><br><br>
            <input type="submit" Value="Send Feedback"><br><br>
        </form> 

        <?php
            if(isset($_POST[fullname]) && $_POST[fullname] != "" && !empty($_POST[fullname])) {
                echo "Hi " . $name . ".<br>";
            }
            else{
                echo "Please enter a name....";
            }

            if(isset($_POST[email]) && $_POST[email] != "" && !empty($_POST[email]) {
                echo "Your email is " . $email . ".<br>";   
            }
            else{
                echo "Please enter a email address.";
            }

            if(isset($_POST[feedback]) && $_POST[feedback] != "") {
                echo "Your feedback is:" . $feedback . "<br>";
            }
            else{
                echo "No feedback.";
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run the page, it shows the name, email and 'Your feedback is: ' but not the feedback that was entered into the textarea.

**EDIT** 
I want to use the nl2br() function round the text box.

Comment: Because `$feedback` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: smitthy you didn't show any interest in getting answer and marking the answer too, so i am deleting my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Change following line to:

```
echo "Your feedback is:" . $text . "<br>";
```

Because you've never assign a value to `$feedback` variable.

Comment: I've already tried that, and it wasn't displaying the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Your code had too many errors I have corrected it, please fin the working code below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .error{color: #FF0000;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Customer Feedback</h1>
        <p1>Please tell us what you think</p1><br><br>

        <?PHP
            $name = trim($_POST[fullname]);
            $email = trim($_POST[email]);
            $text = trim($_POST[feedback]);
        ?>

        <form method='POST' action='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>' >
            <p1>Your name:</p1><br>
            <input type="text" name="fullname" value="<?php echo $fullname; ?>" required><br><br>
            <p1>Your email address:</p1><br>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" required><br><br>
            <p1>Your feedback:</p1><br>
            <textarea rows="5"  cols="50" name="feedback"><?php echo nl2br($text);?></textarea>
            <textarea><?php echo $text;?></textarea><br><br>
            <input type="submit" Value="Send Feedback"><br><br>
        </form> 

        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['fullname']) && $_POST['fullname'] != "" && !empty($_POST['fullname'])) {
                echo "Hi " . $name . ".<br>";
            }
            else{
                echo "Please enter a name....";
            }

            if($_POST['email'] && $_POST['email'] != "" && $_POST['email']) {
                echo "Your email is " . $email . ".<br>";   
            }
            else{
                echo "Please enter a email address.";
            }

            if(isset($_POST['feedback']) && $_POST['feedback'] != "") {
                echo "Your feedback is:" . $_POST['feedback'] . "<br>";
            }
            else{
                echo "No feedback.";
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Anant these are not errors these are notices by PHP. I have corrected the code to the extend that its able to give desired output.

Comment: Dear @Anant respect your concerns for an error free code, what I was more concerned here was to get the desired output as per the question asked and not do do his homework of correcting the entire code.

Comment: This isn't homework. This is me wanting to learn a new language in my free time

Comment: @smitthy if you use `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);` in you code header all php notices will disappear. Further I respect your willingness to learn new language, what I suggest is the more you research and code on your own the more you will learn.

Comment: @smitthy please do update me if the above code works for you.